# HTTP Client Post Async Always Produces Task cancelled in web API project While it is working in console APP c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, console-application, dotnet-httpclient

I have created two projects, one is console application another is WEB API in c#, In this i have called a API using HTTPClient using postAsync method. It is working fine in Console Application (.net Framework 4.7.2). While in Web API (.net Framework 4.7.2) same code is always goes in TaskCanCelled .
Below is code snippet.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + data.token);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "b75b570ad98148968beac9510ecaba6a");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Trace", "false");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = false;
    var postTask = client.PostAsync(data.url, new StringContent(
        new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rAS), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        jsonResponse = postTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Exception i got is something - "A task was canceled.". Same code is working on Console Application. This is very frustrating guys please help.

Comment: You are calling async method why you should include `await` in front of each async method call. As an alternative use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` but not `Result`.

Comment: @ThomasArdal i tried this but same issue. Same is working fine on console that's the main issue.

Comment: So, can you try pasting the updated code you tried in the API?